# Userform will encode data and will create an appointment on Microsoft Outlook Calendar

Tags: vba, outlook, calendar

I have already made a User Form which could encode data on a spreadsheet. In addition to its feature, I would want to create an appointment on Microsoft Outlook Calendar upon clicking a button on the userform.

I have coded for this, but my problem is that it keeps on creating the same appointment of previous data encoded - simply say, there are duplications of appointment on the same day, with the same data.

For example:
I have encoded the Name "Allen" and it will create an appointment on January 1, 2019. The next time a have encoded another data, there will be another appointment on January 1, 2019 with Name "Allen".

This is the code that i am currently using:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

lMaxRows = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
lMaxRows = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
lMaxRows = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
lMaxRows = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row

Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & lMaxRows + 1).Value = TextBox1
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & lMaxRows + 1).Value = TextBox2
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & lMaxRows + 1).Value = TextBox3
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & lMaxRows + 1).Value = "9:00"

Dim oAppt As AppointmentItem
Dim Remind_Time As Double

i = 2
Candidate = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1)

While Candidate <> ""
    Set oAppt = Outlook.Application.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)

        oAppt.Subject = Candidate + " " + ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 2)
        oAppt.Location = ""
        oAppt.Start = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 3)
        Remind_Time = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 4) * 1 * 60
        oAppt.ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = Remind_Time
        oAppt.AllDayEvent = True
        oAppt.Save
    i = i + 1
    Candidate = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1)
Wend
MsgBox "Candidate(s) Added To Outlook Calendar!"
End Sub
```

Comment: You're using a loop to create the appointments, so it will run over all the rows each time you call the code.  If you only need to create a single appointment, don't use a loop.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @TimWilliams. That would mean that I need to delete "While" and "Wend", right?

Comment: Yes and the whole use of `i`.  Just reference the row you just populated.

Comment: Thanks mate @TimWilliams! It is now working perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

Please try clear the Outlook application object, like this below:

Set olAppItem = Nothing

Set olApp = Nothing

```
Sub RegisterAppointmentList() 
' adds a list of appontments to the Calendar in Outlook 
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application 
Dim olAppItem As Outlook.AppointmentItem 
Dim r As Long 

On Error Resume Next 
Worksheets("Schedule").Activate 

Set olApp = GetObject("", "Outlook.Application") 
On Error GoTo 0 
If olApp Is Nothing Then 
    On Error Resume Next 
    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application") 
    On Error GoTo 0 
    If olApp Is Nothing Then 
        MsgBox "Outlook is not available!" 
        Exit Sub 
    End If 
End If 
r = 6 ' first row with appointment data in the active worksheet 
Dim mysub, myStart, myEnd 
While Len(Cells(r, 2).Text) <> 0 
    mysub = Cells(r, 2) & ", " & Cells(r, 3) 
    myStart = DateValue(Cells(r, 5).Value) + Cells(r, 6).Value 
    myEnd = DateValue(Cells(r, 5).Value) + Cells(r, 7).Value 
    'DeleteTestAppointments mysub, myStart, myEnd 
    Set olAppItem = olApp.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem) ' creates a new appointment 
    With olAppItem 
        ' set default appointment values 
        .Location = Cells(r, 3) 
        .Body = "" 
        .ReminderSet = True 
        .BusyStatus = olFree 
        '.RequiredAttendees = "johndoe@microsoft.com" 
        On Error Resume Next 
        .Start = myStart 
        .End = myEnd 
        .Subject = Cells(r, 2) & ", " & .Location 
        .Attachments.Add ("c:\temp\somefile.msg") 
        .Location = Cells(r, 3).Value 
        .Body = .Subject & ", " & Cells(r, 4).Value 
        .ReminderSet = True 
        .BusyStatus = olBusy 
        .Categories = "Orange Category" ' add this to be able to delete the testappointments 
        On Error GoTo 0 
        .Save ' saves the new appointment to the default folder 
    End With 
    r = r + 1 
Wend 
Set olAppItem = Nothing 
Set olApp = Nothing 
MsgBox "Done !"
```

End Sub

Also, did you set the right time for your encoded data or use hard code test data to create appointment? Hope it helps you.