# Word web addin load whole document from server header/footer

Tags: ms-word, ms-office, office-js

We are trying to load a word document from server using JavaScript. We send the document using a base64 encoding. With our current approach, only the body is loading using the function:

```
context.document.body.insertFileFromBase64(fileContent, "replace");
```

Unfortunately, the header and the footer are not loading. Is there another approach to load the whole document including body and footer?

Answer (score 1):

the insertFile operation does not overwrite existing header/footers in the document.

Answer (score 0):

According to my research, I saw this [article](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/issues/1320) for using insertFileFromBase64.The article says," **if you use insertFileFromBase64 to insert the file it does have this blank page with header and footer**." Did you have the same issue for this?

However, another article says it's a design issue. [Userform will encode data and will create an appointment on Microsoft Outlook Calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51924404/userform-will-encode-data-and-will-create-an-appointment-on-microsoft-outlook-ca/51926688)

The article provides approach:

```
function getFile(){
    Office.context.document.getFileAsync(Office.FileType.Compressed, { sliceSize: 4194304  /*64 KB*/ },
      function (result) {
          if (result.status == "succeeded") {
              // If the getFileAsync call succeeded, then
              // result.value will return a valid File Object.
              var myFile = result.value;
              var sliceCount = myFile.sliceCount;
              var slicesReceived = 0, gotAllSlices = true, docdataSlices = [];
              console.log("File size:" + myFile.size + " #Slices: " + sliceCount);

              // Get the file slices.
              getSliceAsync(myFile, 0, sliceCount, gotAllSlices, docdataSlices, slicesReceived);
          }
          else {
              app.showNotification("Error:", result.error.message);
          }
      });



}


function getSliceAsync(file, nextSlice, sliceCount, gotAllSlices, docdataSlices, slicesReceived) {
    file.getSliceAsync(nextSlice, function (sliceResult) {
        if (sliceResult.status == "succeeded") {
            if (!gotAllSlices) { // Failed to get all slices, no need to continue.
                return;
            }

            // Got one slice, store it in a temporary array.
            // (Or you can do something else, such as
            // send it to a third-party server.)
            docdataSlices[sliceResult.value.index] = sliceResult.value.data;
            if (++slicesReceived == sliceCount) {
                // All slices have been received.
                file.closeAsync();
                onGotAllSlices(docdataSlices);
            }
            else {
                getSliceAsync(file, ++nextSlice, sliceCount, gotAllSlices, docdataSlices, slicesReceived);
            }
        }
        else {
            gotAllSlices = false;
            file.closeAsync();
            console.log("getSliceAsync Error:", sliceResult.error.message);
        }
    });
}

function onGotAllSlices(docdataSlices) {
    var docdata = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < docdataSlices.length; i++) {
        docdata = docdata.concat(docdataSlices[i]);
    }
    var fileContent = new String();

    for (var j = 0; j < docdata.length; j++) {
        fileContent += String.fromCharCode(docdata[j]);
    }




    var mybase64 = window.btoa(fileContent);
    console.log("here is the base 64", mybase64);
    // Now all the file content is stored in 'fileContent' variable,
    // you can do something with it, such as print, fax...
}
```